# Formatting column names with sed /awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have an input file (3GB file) with the first column as the Chromosome name. I want to change it to the form as SL4.0ch03 => Chr3, SL4.0ch10 => Chr10, SL4.0ch00 => Chr0, and so on. How can I achieve this with sed /awk ? Thanks

```
SL4.0ch03   59223349    59223349    5.75E-08    0.00111266  -100    10990
SL4.0ch03   59223326    59223326    2.06E-07    0.001995114 -93.75  10989
SL4.0ch03   59223302    59223302    3.12E-06    0.020132332 -75 10988
SL4.0ch03   59223436    59223436    9.61E-06    0.046493287 -91.66666667    10991
SL4.0ch12   35715705    35715705    5.91E-05    0.228665834 -69.11764706    17608
SL4.0ch08   9288225 9288225 0.000238929 0.770238788 76.66666667 12452
SL4.0ch10   56633780    56633780    0.000364489 0.994208339 -76.92307692    16129
SL4.0ch11   8632482 8632482 0.000682559 0.994208339 48.59335038 16401
SL4.0ch00   9242670 9242670 0.00069965  0.994208339 -60 9122
SL4.0ch12   36752695    36752695    0.000862206 0.994208339 -60.78431373    17813
SL4.0ch04   54892467    54892467    0.000912131 0.994208339 60  11494
SL4.0ch00   6521558 6521558 0.001145063 0.994208339 50  7459
SL4.0ch00   2138791 2138791 0.001268281 0.994208339 56.98529412 1820
SL4.0ch00   683820  683820  0.001482525 0.994208339 62.5    762
```

Comment: please add what you've tried yourself to solve this, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info if you need learning resources for sed... that said, using `pr + cut` will be much faster compared to sed/awk here if you don't mind having `Chr03` instead of `Chr3`

Comment: just tested, `paste + cut` will be faster, `pr + cut` is slower than `sed`.. hmm...

Comment: What's your field separator (multiple spaces or one tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient approach would be a single call to `awk` to manipulate the first field and write the record back out. (likely orders of magnitude faster on a 3G file) You can reformat the first field using `sub()` and `substr()` and then concatenate `"Chr"` to the beginning to make the substitution you want. For example, you can do:

```
awk '{sub(/[.][0-9]+ch/,"",$1);n=substr($1,4);n=n+0;$1="Chr" n}1' file
```

Where the first `sub()` eliminates everything from the `'.'` through the `"ch"`. The use of `substr()` assigns the remaining numbers to `n`, (e.g. `n` would contain `"03"`). You remove the leading `'0'` by using `n` in simple arithmetic (e.g. `n=n+0`) to have `n` evaluated as a number. Finally a simple concatenation between `"Chr"` and `n` leaves you your desired output, e.g.

```
$ awk '{sub(/[.][0-9]+ch/,"",$1);n=substr($1,4);n=n+0;$1="Chr" n}1' file
Chr3 59223349 59223349 5.75E-08 0.00111266 -100 10990
Chr3 59223326 59223326 2.06E-07 0.001995114 -93.75 10989
Chr3 59223302 59223302 3.12E-06 0.020132332 -75 10988
Chr3 59223436 59223436 9.61E-06 0.046493287 -91.66666667 10991
Chr12 35715705 35715705 5.91E-05 0.228665834 -69.11764706 17608
Chr8 9288225 9288225 0.000238929 0.770238788 76.66666667 12452
Chr10 56633780 56633780 0.000364489 0.994208339 -76.92307692 16129
Chr11 8632482 8632482 0.000682559 0.994208339 48.59335038 16401
Chr0 9242670 9242670 0.00069965 0.994208339 -60 9122
Chr12 36752695 36752695 0.000862206 0.994208339 -60.78431373 17813
Chr4 54892467 54892467 0.000912131 0.994208339 60 11494
Chr0 6521558 6521558 0.001145063 0.994208339 50 7459
Chr0 2138791 2138791 0.001268281 0.994208339 56.98529412 1820
Chr0 683820 683820 0.001482525 0.994208339 62.5 762
```

(if you want `'\t'` separated output, you can set `OFS="\t"`)

To preserve the original spacing (varying no. of spaces in your posted data), you can use:

```
awk '{f=$1; sub(/[.][0-9]+ch/,"",f);n=substr(f,4);n=n+0;f="Chr" n;sub($1,f)}1' file
```

Output is then:

```
Chr3   59223349    59223349    5.75E-08    0.00111266  -100    10990
Chr3   59223326    59223326    2.06E-07    0.001995114 -93.75  10989
Chr3   59223302    59223302    3.12E-06    0.020132332 -75 10988
Chr3   59223436    59223436    9.61E-06    0.046493287 -91.66666667    10991
Chr12   35715705    35715705    5.91E-05    0.228665834 -69.11764706    17608
Chr8   9288225 9288225 0.000238929 0.770238788 76.66666667 12452
Chr10   56633780    56633780    0.000364489 0.994208339 -76.92307692    16129
Chr11   8632482 8632482 0.000682559 0.994208339 48.59335038 16401
Chr0   9242670 9242670 0.00069965  0.994208339 -60 9122
Chr12   36752695    36752695    0.000862206 0.994208339 -60.78431373    17813
Chr4   54892467    54892467    0.000912131 0.994208339 60  11494
Chr0   6521558 6521558 0.001145063 0.994208339 50  7459
Chr0   2138791 2138791 0.001268281 0.994208339 56.98529412 1820
Chr0   683820  683820  0.001482525 0.994208339 62.5    762
```

Let me know if that will work for your purposes. There are several ways to write the field 1 manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script:

```
  cat Inputfile |  awk 'BEGIN {FS = " ";} { print $1}' | awk 'BEGIN { FS ="ch";i = 0;}{i = int($2); print "s/" $1 "ch" $2 "/Chr" i "/";}' | xargs -I {} sed -i {}  Inputfile
```

The output:

```
cat inputile |  awk 'BEGIN {FS = " ";} { print $1}' | awk 'BEGIN { FS 
="ch";i = 0;}{i = int($2); print "s/" $1 "ch" $2 "/Chr" i "/";}' | xargs -I {} 
sed -i {} inputile  & cat inputile 
[1] 8825
Chr3   59223349    59223349    5.75E-08    0.00111266  -100    10990
Chr3   59223326    59223326    2.06E-07    0.001995114 -93.75  10989
Chr3   59223302    59223302    3.12E-06    0.020132332 -75 10988
Chr3   59223436    59223436    9.61E-06    0.046493287 -91.66666667    10991
Chr12   35715705    35715705    5.91E-05    0.228665834 -69.11764706    17608
Chr8   9288225 9288225 0.000238929 0.770238788 76.66666667 12452
Chr10   56633780    56633780    0.000364489 0.994208339 -76.92307692    16129
Chr11   8632482 8632482 0.000682559 0.994208339 48.59335038 16401
Chr0   9242670 9242670 0.00069965  0.994208339 -60 9122
Chr12   36752695    36752695    0.000862206 0.994208339 -60.78431373    17813
Chr4   54892467    54892467    0.000912131 0.994208339 60  11494
Chr0   6521558 6521558 0.001145063 0.994208339 50  7459
Chr0   2138791 2138791 0.001268281 0.994208339 56.98529412 1820
Chr0   683820  683820  0.001482525 0.994208339 62.5    762
```

Comment: I checked it and it works correctly. It seems complicated for you and for me it's straightforward. I just used two awk commands.

Comment: well, I checked again, the `xargs` portion doesn't work for me.. but it works if I replace `xargs` with `sed -f-`  ... a simpler solution woulld be `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {split($1, a, "ch"); $1="Chr" int(a[2])} 1'`

Comment: Ok. I added the output of the script to answer. I checked it in fedora 31.

Answer (score 1):

Wih `bash`:

```
while read -r first rest; do
  [[ $first =~ ([0-9]+)$ ]] && echo -e "Chr${BASH_REMATCH[1]#0*}\t$rest"
done < file
```

Output:

```
Chr3    59223349    59223349    5.75E-08    0.00111266  -100    10990
Chr3    59223326    59223326    2.06E-07    0.001995114 -93.75  10989
Chr3    59223302    59223302    3.12E-06    0.020132332 -75 10988
Chr3    59223436    59223436    9.61E-06    0.046493287 -91.66666667    10991
Chr12   35715705    35715705    5.91E-05    0.228665834 -69.11764706    17608
Chr8    9288225 9288225 0.000238929 0.770238788 76.66666667 12452
Chr10   56633780    56633780    0.000364489 0.994208339 -76.92307692    16129
Chr11   8632482 8632482 0.000682559 0.994208339 48.59335038 16401
Chr0    9242670 9242670 0.00069965  0.994208339 -60 9122
Chr12   36752695    36752695    0.000862206 0.994208339 -60.78431373    17813
Chr4    54892467    54892467    0.000912131 0.994208339 60  11494
Chr0    6521558 6521558 0.001145063 0.994208339 50  7459
Chr0    2138791 2138791 0.001268281 0.994208339 56.98529412 1820
Chr0    683820  683820  0.001482525 0.994208339 62.5    762
```

Certainly not the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `\t` is the field separator:

```
sed -E 's/^[^\t]+ch0*([0-9])/Chr\1/'
```

- `^[^\t]+ch` will match until the last occurrence of `ch` in the first field
- `0*([0-9])` to remove all leading zeroes except if `0` is the last digit
- `Chr\1` replace with `Chr` and the digit that was captured

With `paste + cut` for a faster solution (compared to `sed -E 's/^.{7}/Chr/'`)

```
paste -d'Chr' /dev/null /dev/null /dev/null <(cut -c8- ip.txt)
```

This will not remove the leading zeroes though and assumes you always need to change only the first 7 characters.

Another solution with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     match($1,/([1-9][0-9]*|0)$/){$1 = "Chr" substr($1,RSTART)}
     1' ip.txt
```